# Java Scanner Delimiter Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, hashmap

I am currently attempting to write a program that uses a scanner with a custom delimiter to create a hashmap of words in a text file. Everything is working correctly to the most degree, but I have one error: my hashmap includes a blank key for its first entry, even though I have attempted to curtail this using if statements. What am I doing wrong? I am assuming that it has something to do with my regular expression and characters that are not printed in the console.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Gettys {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Takes input from file and creates an alphabetical mapping of the words within the file
        File file = new File("src/gettys.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        input.useDelimiter("\\s|\\p{Punct}");
        TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
            if (map.containsKey(word) && word != "" && word != null) {
                map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
            }
            else if (word != "" && word != null) {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
        }// end while loop
        
        System.out.print(map);
    }// end main
}//end class
```

The output is as follows: {=37, a=7, above=1, add=1, advanced=1, ago=1, all=1, altogether=1, ... etc

The text file is a text file of the Gettysburg address. After some debugging I realized that the problems only occur where punctuation is in the file.

Here is the text of the file:

Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.

Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battlefield of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.

But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate we can not consecrate we can not hallow this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.

Any help is appreciated! Sorry if this is longwinded.

Comment: `word != ""` should be `word.length() > 0`. String comparisons with `==` won't work here.

Comment: In your regex, change \\s to \\s+